# Check null character in assembly language

Tags: string, assembly, null

I am new to assembly language. To be clear, this is homework. The problem is given a char *list, how can I find which character is the end of the string?
So I have

```
xor ecx, ecx; //counter
loop1:
mov esi, list;
mov eax, [esi + ecx];
cmp eax, 0x00; //check if the character is null
je end;
inc ecx;
jmp loop1;

end:
```

however, the loop does not terminate when it reaches the end of the string. I wonder what I have done wrong. I have been finding solution in books and online, but they all look like what I did. Any help will be appreciated!

EDIT: yes, counter should be outside of the loop.

Comment: Does it fail with one specific testcase or all? Did you try the empty string?

Comment: Could you give the full source ? how is the list defined ? is it read from user input ? is it statically defined in data section ?

Comment: The input is for example "Hello World", the loop should terminate after "d", but it didn't.

Comment: Resetting the counter to zero on every iteration is *probably* not what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You should not reset the counter as part of the loop.
- You should not initialize the address as part of the loop.
- The zero-termination is just a single byte but you test a complete dword.
- The fewer jumps the better code you've written

Putting all of this together we get

```
  mov esi, list
  mov ecx, -1
loop1:
  inc ecx
  cmp byte [esi + ecx], 0x00; //check if the character is null
  jne loop1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are reading several bytes at a time, and testing if they are all zero.

Try to read just one byte instead:

```
mov al, [esi + ecx];
cmp al, 0x00; //check if the character is null
```